# What's wrong in this solution? (integral, substitute)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

Please help me to find what's wrong with the answer to the calculation of:

$$\int_{1}^{1+2 \pi} (\cos x) e^{-(\sin x)^2} dx$$

Let $t=\sin x$

$dt = \cos x dx$

$x=1 \implies t=\sin 1$,

$x=1+2\pi \implies t=\sin 1$

So the integral is

$$\int_{\sin 1}^{\sin 1}e^{-t^2}dt=0$$

Comment: You can use this [page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) as a guide to LaTeX usage here. If I understand your notation, I think your approach is correct and the integral is 0.

Comment: It's a question from homework, they ask what's wrong..

Comment: @Jean Marie Thanks!

Comment: Your error comes from the fact that the change of variables $t=\sin(x)$ cannot be a bijection when you take the domain $1 \le x \le 1+2\pi$. $\sin$ function is bijective for example from $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ onto $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Ok but why it cannot be bijective?

Comment: Because for example if you define $t_0:=sin(1)$, as $sin(\pi-1)=sin(1)=t_0$ in particular, this means that $1$ and $\pi-1$ have the same image $t_0$. Not a good point for a bijection...

Comment: Except there is no requirement in variable substitution that the substitution be a bijection. This integral is $0$. A continuously differentiable substitution works whether it is bijective or not.